# mCustomScrollbar don't update after add new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mcustomscrollbar

This full my code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoanghoang3009/cbvmxrpk/). After I add new list element by jquery, I use update to scrollbar update new list but new list overflow out tag ul store it.

This code to create list element dynamic (line 46-50 in jsfiddle):

```
    var d = new Date();
    var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
        for (var i=1990; i<=currentYear; i++) {
        $("#expandYear ul").append("<li><a href=\"#\">"+ i +"</a></li><li role=\"separator\" class=\"divider\"></li>");
    }
```

This code to update mcustom scrollbar (line 52-61 in jsfiddle):

```
   $("#expandYear ul").mCustomScrollbar({ 
      advanced:{ 
         updateOnContentResize: true,
         updateOnImageLoad: true,
         updateOnSelectorChange: "ul",
         updateOnSelectorChange: "ul li",
      } 
   });

   $("#expandYear ul").mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

Library custom scrollbar I use: [http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `mCustomScrollbar` class from your `ul` element - this is messing up the overflow CSS and the plugin will add it for you after initialisation anyway.